# Is MySQL stored procedure precompiled?

Tags: mysql

I am using Winform C# and MySQL.

My friend is using SQL.

He said that MySQL does not have stored procedures. But I reject that, because I am already using this SP in MySQL. And he said that it's a function not a SP. SP is precompiled.

I am very confused.

Here is my SP.

```
BEGIN

    insert into bonafide_records (date,admin_no,name,CreationId) values (date_a,admin_no_a,name_a,CreationId_a);

END
```

Please clear this for me, does MySQL have SP?

Comment: Having friends who don't know what they're talking about sometimes really shouldn't make you "very confused".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL's do have stored procedures:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE PROCEDURE `p2` ()
LANGUAGE SQL
DETERMINISTIC
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
COMMENT 'A procedure'
BEGIN
    SELECT 'Hello World !';
END//
```

REF: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/mysql-and-stored-procedures/5178706

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedures and stored functions were supported in MySQL 5.0 - [CREATE PROCEDURE and CREATE FUNCTION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html) .

Maybe your friend meant UDFs, which are compiled (C, C++,...) functions. Find more information here - [Adding New Functions to MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-functions.html).

Comment: Are stored functions precompiled?

Answer (score -1):

you can use stored procedures in MySQL:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines.html